# How to execute joins and populations efficiently in MongoDB (with Mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 schemas: `Category`, `Subcategory`, `Product`

- A `Subcategory` has a field called "category" which is `ObjectId` referencing the parent `Category`.
- And a `Product` has a field called "subcategory" which is `ObjectId` referencing the parent `Subcategory`.

My question is how can i query (preferably a single one) a full "topology" of these collections to achieve this result:

```
{ 
  "categories": [{
    "subcategories": [{
      "products": [{
        ...
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

I know I can just have multiple queries but I'm looking for a better more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) from [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/) to achieve this.